# Difference between 2 dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, difference

I have 2 "timestamp" columns in a table, in a Postgres database. I need to extract the difference in days between these 2 columns. Let's consider the columns are "column1" and "column2". And the difference between these 2 timestamps is 10 hours. 
So, for the query:

```
select column2 - column1 from table
```

The result is of "interval" type, and it is "10:00:00". I need to convert this in a real number, and, for this example, to obtain the result as something like "0.41666...7"

Comment: `I need to convert this in a real number` I am not sure what you mean? For example what would be the value for 10:32:41?

Comment: "real number" - equivalent to a "double" value in Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the number of seconds from the resulting interval using `extract()`

```
select extract(epoch from column2 - column1)
from the_table;
```

If you divide that by 86400 to get it as a fraction of a day

Answer (score 2):

```
DATE_PART('day', column2 - column1)
```

http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff

Comment: This returns an integer value. And I need a value with decimals. With date_part, the result is "0".

Comment: See the reference I linked. DATE_PART('hour', end - start )/24 should give you the extra fractional part of a day. So whole answer would be DATE_PART('day', column2 - column1) + DATE_PART('hour', end - start )/24

Comment: This seems like it might look purely at the minute, without consideration of the other denominators e.g. for `DATE_PART('minute', time_1 - time_2) < 1`, I'm getting time_1 = 2019-06-21 09:32:45.073002 and time_2 = 2019-06-24 04:32:47.779387 returned